# Return Average of a column if

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

Looking to return average if criteria is met, but I can't get the formula to work when one of my criteria exists in multiple columns. Does anyone have an efficient solution?

`=AVERAGEIFS(Sheet2!D:D,Sheet2!A:A,A2,Sheet2!B:C,B2)`

[image: Sheet2 Screenshot:]

Comment: Welcome! Do you mean something like as `=AVERAGE(FILTER(D:D,(A:A=A2)*((B:B=B2)+(C:C=B2))))`?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. JohnSUN already showed how to do it with `filter()`. Here's how you would do it with `query()`:

```
=query( 
  Sheet2!A$1:D, 
  "select avg(D) 
   where A = '" & A2 & "' 
   and(B = '" & B2 & "' or C = '" & B2 & "') 
   label avg(D) '' ", 0 
)
```